# How can you get the size of vector as an int?

Tags: c++, vector

I'm used to languages where `.Length` or whatever it may be returns an `int` but I'm taking a C++ class so I gotta know how to do this. I asked my professor to explain but she didn't want to because the rest of the class is learning about arrays.

First of all, I don't think I fully understand what it is that `.size` returns. How do I cast whatever `.size` is to an `int`? If it's not efficient to do this, how do I loop over the elements of a vector?

Comment: As for the question "how do I loop over the elements of a vector": `for (const auto& element : v) { ... }`

Comment: You can always look at the documentation. Also, you should expect `size` to return some sort of integer. You don't need to cast it to `int`, which is also undesirable for very large vectors with an element count greater than the maximum size of an `int`. Don't cast unless you have a *good* reason to, and you do not.

Comment: Use an `int` when you need a signed value.  Use a `size_t` when you need the size of something, which is always unsigned.

Comment: You can cast it to an int with int(value_returned_by_size). You can think of size_t as an integer, it is formally a separate type to handle systems where the size of memory is different from the size of an int

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::vector::size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) is a member function. You have to call it and it returns the size of the vector. You want to use `.size()` not `.size`. Using `.size` refers to the function (for example if you want to take it's address) where as `.size()` calls the function.

There are several ways of looping over a vector. The most generic method is the [range-based for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). It works with all standard containers, any user-defined container that provides a proper `begin` and `end` method, as well as arrays. For example :

```
for(const auto & element: my_vect) {
    proc(element);
}
```

Will call the function `proc` with every element in the vector `my_vect`.

Comment: @rcgldr The size returned is `std::vector::size_type` which is usually (but not necessarily) `std::size_t`. It depends on the allocator and you can provide a different allocator with a size_type that isn't `std::size_t`. User defined containers can also choose to alias `size_type` to whatever type they prefer.

Comment: Deleted my prior comment. I should have used size_type, not size_t. My point was that int and size_type are usually not the same, especially in 64 bit mode with most compilers targeting X86-64.

Answer (score 0):

Class `std::vector` has a member function `size()` which returns the number of elements pushed in. So use it to get the size as an integer value:

```
std::vector<int> vecInt;
vecInt.push_back(1);
vecInt.push_back(2);
vecInt.push_back(3);
vecInt.push_back(4);
vecInt.push_back(5);

std::cout << vecInt.size(); // 5
```